# How to evaluate Named Entity Recognition for an ASR output?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, speech-recognition, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to evaluate the output of an Automated Speech Recognition system for the recognition of named entities.

I currently have access to an API that detects named entities. The aim is not to evaluate this API, but to evaluate the ASR output. So we can assume that this system detects properly NE.

So for an ASR output, I also have a reference (Gold standard) text.
I would like to calculate the precision and recall of the ASR system when it comes to NE.

So far my approach is:

- Send the reference text to the API and get a list of named entities for the whole text.
- Send the ASR output text to the API and get a list of named entities in the output.
- Compare both lists and find: True Positives (entities in the reference list of named entities that are also in the list of output entities), False Negatives (if there is an entity detected in the reference list that is not in the output list) and False Positives (there is an entity detected in the output list that is not in the reference list)
- Calculate precision and recall

The API also returns the position of the entities. I thought about using it to check for the "matching" entities in the output text but in case an entity is missed or the spelling is different, it cannot be used.

I do not perform any normalization as we want to take into account capitalization, and we decided it needs a perfect match.

Is this approach correct or are there other aspects to take into account?
Thank you